# Is "neither have I wings to fly" grammatically correct?

Tags: grammar, lyrics

I came across this sentence "And neither have I wings to fly" in the lyric of the song "The Water Is Wide". Shouldn't it be "... neither I have ..."? Or it is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is correct as it stands.  The sentence-initial negative adverb causes an inversion of word order.  Most adverbs don't have this effect in English, but a few do so.  (For German speakers, this is a remnant of the V2 rule.)

"Some adverbs (e.g. *hardly, little, never, only, scarcely* and *seldom*) have a negative meaning. When we use these at the beginning of the clause, we invert the subject and verb: **Hardly** had we left the hotel when it started to pour with rain." ( https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/negative-adverbs-hardly-seldom-etc )

See also Lexico's example sentence at "neither" adv. 2 ("Used to introduce a further negative statement. *‘he didn't remember, and neither did I’*" https://www.lexico.com/definition/neither )

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/607837/2085).